# Find Hermitian interpolation with Lagrangian polynomials

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, lagrange-interpolation, hermite-polynomials

Hi I have an exercise that I cannot solve.

Can someone help me?

I have to find the solution to the following Hermitian interpolation problem p(x) under the conditions:

$p(x_0)=-1, \ p'(x_0)=1 \ p(x_1)=1$
for $x_0=0$ and $x_1=1$ using the generalized Lagrangian polynomials.

Can someone help me?

I don't know how to start solving the problem.

Comment: Use the square of the lagragian polynomials

Comment: I don't get it. How can this help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L_i(x)$ be the Lagrangian polynomial associated with $x_i$ and $q_i(x)=L_i(x)^2$, then try to see what conditions on $P_i(x)$ can make the polynomial $P = \sum_i q_i(x) P_i(x)$ solve your problem. Here you just have a sum of two products since you have two points but this idea will work for an arbitrary number of points to interpolate

Hint :
${\displaystyle q_{i}(x_{i})=1,\quad q_{i}^{\prime }(x_{i})=\sum _{j=0,j\neq i}^{n}{\frac {2}{x_{i}-x_{j}}}\quad {\rm {and}}\quad \forall j\neq i\quad q_{i}^{\prime }(x_{j})=q_{i}(x_{j})=0}$

Hint 2 : search $P_i$ as a polynomial of degree 1